# qPCR from tissue to compare T-cell subpopulations

Tags: immunology, pcr

In the experiment, groups of mice have been intranasally immunised with different vaccine formulations. We have stored nasal tissue (basically, the front part of the skull without muscles, brain, etc.)

Hypothesis: local T-cell subpopulations differ between groups.

Problem: we don't have access to flow cytometry, therefore we would like to compare RNA expression from bulk RNA with the qPCR.

Question:

1. due to very small amount of T-cell RNA from nasal tissue, is it even plausible to try (anyone has done similar tissue bulk RNA processing?)
2. which housekeeping genes would be best candidates for further work (see [Why are some housekeeping genes considered better?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34130/why-are-some-housekeeping-genes-considered-better))(any links appreciated)